# How can I search an XML file and get multiple results and put them in a table in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, search

I need to be able to search an XML file and find all of the results that match the criteria that the user enters. There are around 1000 records in the XML file. There are five fields: "Lesson Name," "Start Date," "Complete", "CompleteDate", and "Code." After the results are found, they are to be put into an HTML table.

XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<lessons>
  <lesson>
    <code>4889</code>
    <lessonname>Lesson 1</lessonname>
    <startdate>2016-03-03 00:59:43</startdate>
    <complete>1</complete>
    <completedate>2016-03-03 01:35:19</completedate>
  </lesson>
  <lesson>
    <code>4889</code>
    <lessonname>Lesson 2</lessonname>
    <startdate>2016-03-18 00:30:00</startdate>
    <complete>1</complete>
    <completedate>2016-03-03 01:35:19</completedate>
  </lesson>
</lessons>
```

At this point, I am able to get all of the records from the XML file and put them into a table. However, I want to limit the results to only the ones that match what the user types into the textboxes. I am unsure of how to filter the results. Here is what I've tried:

jQuery Code

```js
function getXmlDataFromAPI() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pathToFile",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      var totalRowsReturned = xml.childNodes[0].childElementCount;
      var lessonName = document.getElementById("lessonNameBox").value;
      var startDate = document.getElementById("startDateBox").value;
      var code = document.getElementById("codeBox").value;

      $(xml).find('lesson').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('lessonname').text() == lessonName) {
          var col0 = $(this).find('code').text();
          var col1 = $(this).find('startdate').text();
          var col2 = $(this).find('lessonname').text();
          var col3 = $(this).find('complete').text();
          var col4 = $(this).find('completedate').text();
          $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>' + col0 + '</td><td>' + col1 + '</td><td>' + col2 + '</td><td>' + col3 + '</td><td>'
                              + col4 + '</td>').appendTo('#apiXmlTable');
        }
        else {
          alert("The criteria you entered does not match any of the records on file.");
        }

      });

      //make the table-containing div, clear button, the table, and the total results box visible 
      $("#apiXmlTable").show();
      $("#xmlTableContainer").show();
      $("#clearTableBtn").show();
      $("#ipt_totalResultsBox").show();
      $("#resultsLabel").show();

      //set the text for the total results box
      document.getElementById("ipt_totalResultsBox").value = totalRowsReturned;
      //make the search button invisible
      $("#searchBtn").css("display", "none");
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      alert("The data could not be retrieved.");
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, this gets all of the data from the xml file and puts it into the table. How can I filter the results based on the user inputs? Also, I'd like to show the total number of results found. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Comment: @MoshFeu I'm afraid I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), [bin](http://jsbin.com/)

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for the tip. I'm hesitant to include a snippet because the data is company data and it is very sensitive. Is there some other way that I could clarify the question?

Comment: you can insert demy data just for the principal.